# Testing multiple databases in Junit testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, multiple-databases

I am trying to test a spring boot application that has two databases. But there are some errors that I can't solve.

I have shared the application.properties file, test class and the error below. Please give me a solution for this.

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=billing-provision-application-service-test

#1st database
spring.billing.datasource.jdbcUrl =jdbc:h2:mem:billing;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;IGNORECASE=TRUE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS billing;
spring.billing.datasource.username=sa
spring.billing.datasource.password=
spring.billing.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.billing.database-platform=h2
spring.billing.datasource.name=billing

#2nd database
spring.ideabizadmin.datasource.jdbcUrl =jdbc:h2:mem:ideabizadmin;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;IGNORECASE=TRUE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ideabizadmin; 
spring.ideabizadmin.datasource.username=sa 
spring.ideabizadmin.datasource.password=
spring.ideabizadmin.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.ideabizadmin.database-platform=h2
spring.ideabizadmin.datasource.name=ideabizadmin

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@SpringBootTest
class AppDetailsRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private AppDetailsRepository appDetailsRepository;

    @Before
    @Transactional("billingTransactionManager")
    void init(){
        AppDetails appDetails = new AppDetails(1,1,1,"testApp");
        appDetailsRepository.save(appDetails);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional("billingTransactionManager")
    void getCurrentMonthAppCount() {
        this.init();
        Integer expected = appDetailsRepository.getCurrentMonthAppCount("01-03-2022","31-03-2022");
        assertEquals(expected,1);
    }
}
```

Error

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select appdetails0_.billing_app_id as billing_1_0_0_, appdetails0_.created_by as created_2_0_0_, appdetails0_.created_date as created_3_0_0_, appdetails0_.last_modified_by as last_mod4_0_0_, appdetails0_.last_modified_date as last_mod5_0_0_, appdetails0_.am_id as am_id6_0_0_, appdetails0_.app_id as app_id7_0_0_, appdetails0_.app_name as app_name8_0_0_ from billing.app_details appdetails0_ where appdetails0_.billing_app_id=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "BILLING" not found; SQL statement:
select appdetails0_.billing_app_id as billing_1_0_0_, appdetails0_.created_by as created_2_0_0_, appdetails0_.created_date as created_3_0_0_, appdetails0_.last_modified_by as last_mod4_0_0_, appdetails0_.last_modified_date as last_mod5_0_0_, appdetails0_.am_id as am_id6_0_0_, appdetails0_.app_id as app_id7_0_0_, appdetails0_.app_name as app_name8_0_0_ from billing.app_details appdetails0_ where appdetails0_.billing_app_id=? [90079-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:576)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    ...128 more
```

Comment: Please post the text not images
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have posted the code in the text. @HariHaravelan

Comment: Create schema if not exist statement does not work but I can not see datasourve configuration